# to include dll file in java without jar files

Tags: java, dll

I have to include `.net` **"SMSMiracle.dll"** in java. I don't have any jar files. I imported the `dll` file to the project using `System.loadLibrary()`. Tell me how to call the files in java?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use JNI or better use a library like [Java Native Access](https://github.com/twall/jna)